# C++ - Why compiler doesn't allow to assign volatile variable

Tags: c++, volatile, non-volatile

What is the reason that the compiler doesn't autogenerate the volatile assignment operator, thus preventing the assignment?

A minimal example:

```
  struct A{};
  A a;
  volatile A b;
  b = a;
```

Comment: I always wanted to meet the person in a million who actually needs this. What is your use case? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: which assignment is prevented? Please clarify the question. What do you expect to be autogenerated?

Comment: I think we need context for this question. Please post a small example of cases where you need a volatile assignment! And I don't even understand *what* you want to be autogenerated, so, that might need some clarification, please :)

Comment: I am using a class from the library and need it to be volatile.

Comment: what class? Don't make a mystery out of it, let us know, share what you found already. Post a [mcve]

Comment: `A` is not a class from the library, is it? What library?

Comment: I need volatile and if I read the new c++ standard correctly,it is the only allowed use case now. I want to read/write to a hardware address on embedded systems. E.g. an fpga/arm combination to access the mapped address in fpga from ARM.

Comment: You say the class is from a library. If they want volatile for some reason, it's up to them to create the appropriate `operator=`.

Comment: This is a minimal example, I just want to know what was the reason for not autogenerating it.

Comment: "why does some type from a library not have the assignemnt operator?" and "why does my struct A not have it?" are two rather different questions. Anyhow it seems to be the latter and thats also what the answer considers.

Comment: volatile simply does NOT apply to C++ objects. It is used for a variable (or sometimes very rarely to a member function). volatile mostly is used to tell the compiler NOT to remove read/writes to these variables when optmizing (always read/write directly to memory). So what do you think you are doing with this? One thing it will not do is make your code threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean why when you create a class

```
class C {
  // assignment operator auto generated
};
```

The assignment operator you get is

```
C& operator=(C const&) = default;
```

and not

```
C volatile& operator=(C volatile const&) volatile = default;
```

So a volatile glvalue cannot be on either side.

The reason is likely cost related. Volatile objects inhibit certain optimizations, and the qualifier sticks to sub-objects (both under pain of `const_cast`). They are also very rare in the wild, like really, practically no one ever declares volatile class objects. If C++ generated a volatile assignment operator by default, all code will need to pay a cost by default, even though they don't use volatile objects. But C++ is designed with the opposing philosophy, we don't pay for what we don't use.

If you are dealing with a library that necessitates the creation of volatile objects, and it breaks on this, then it is poorly designed. But honestly, it's far more likely the library never banked on having its objects declared volatile, and so perhaps it is you who should reconsider doing so.

Comment: While I understand that volatile class objects aren't widespread in general, there is one specific class of objects that *is* used a lot and that does have volatile properties: atomics. For these, the volatile properties are so important that they are baked into the compiler. You get them even without using `volatile`. But that is not specified anywhere and happens just by convention (or call it quality-of-implementation).

Comment: in this case the question will be why 
`volatile C& operator=(const C& a)volatile`
is not generated

Comment: @j6t the guarantees of atomic operations are completely different to the guarantees of `volatile` operations. It's a common misunderstanding, that causes all kinds of bugs, that `volatile` has anything to do with atomic

Comment: @Igor - Your question is only a more limited form of the more general operator, and the reasoning doesn't change.

Comment: @Caleth I'm not at all talking about the special handling of `volatile` that is customary on Windows. I mean that compilers [tend to simplify](https://godbolt.org/z/d8YeG17Ps) `T progress{}; for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) { ++progress; }` to `T progress{100};` when `T` is `int` but not when `T` is `std::atomic<int>`.

Comment: @j6t they are permitted to do that for either. `volatile` means that *something outside this process* has the ability to read or write the object at that location. atomic ensures there is a "happens before" relation between loads and stores to objects within one process

Comment: @j6t "_tend to_" is important there. As mentioned above, the compilers are allowed to still do the same optimization. They currently simply chose not do so, because of  user assumptions such as yours. I wouldn't bet on compiler developers not changing their mind at some point.